# Where are the environment variables in Docker containers coming from?

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio, environment-variables

I have made a Docker installation for a C# application, and I'm having some issues with the environment (more especially the `DOTNET_VERSION`, but also the others as can be seen in the "Inspect" tab of Docker-compose). In order to understand the whole situation, I would like to know where the Docker installation gets the mentioned information from. (I didn't find anything in the C# Visual Studio `*.csproj` file, nor in the Docker(-compose) related `*.yml` files.)

This is what the current "Inspect" page looks like:

Environment

| -------- | -------------- |
| --- | --- |
| DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER | 1 |
| ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS | true |
| ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT | Development |
| ASPNETCORE_URLS | https://+:443;http://+:80 |
| NUGET_PACKAGES | /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages5 |
| NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES | /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages;...;/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages5 |
| PATH | /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin |
| DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER | true |
| DOTNET_VERSION | 5.0.17 |
| ASPNET_VERSION | 5.0.17 |

Mounts

| -------- | -------------- |
| --- | --- |
| /APP | C:\Firm\Projecten...\Server\Connections\ConnectionsSvc |
| /REMOTE_DEBUGGER | C:\Users\Usr\vsdbg\vs2017u5 |
| /SRC | /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/Firm/Projecten/.../AnotherSvc |
| /ROOT/.NUGET/FALLBACKPACKAGES4 | C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder |
| /ROOT/.NUGET/FALLBACKPACKAGES5 | C:\Users\Usr.nuget\packages\ |
| /ROOT/.ASPNET/HTTPS | C:\Users\Usr\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https |
| /ROOT/.MICROSOFT/USERSECRETS | C:\Users\Usr\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets |
| /ROOT/.NUGET/FALLBACKPACKAGES | C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 21.2\Components\Offline Packages |
| /ROOT/.NUGET/FALLBACKPACKAGES2 | C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages |
| /ROOT/.NUGET/FALLBACKPACKAGES3 | C:\Program Files (x86)\Progress\ToolboxNuGetPackages |

Ports

| -------- | -------------- |
| --- | --- |
| 443/tcp | 0.0.0.0:49154 |
| 80/tcp | 0.0.0.0:5128 |

**Edit after comments from Benoit.Be:**
Pardon my ignorance, but I have no idea where to look for the `FROM ...` entry you mention.
I'll show you what my "DockerCompose" directory looks like (it's on a Windows computer, but I use a WSL for launching commandline commands):

```
Prompt> ls -ltra
total 12
-rwxrwxrwx 1 usr usr 5602 Oct  4 09:44 docker-compose.yml
drwxrwxrwx 1 usr usr 4096 Oct  4 09:47 mssqlserver
drwxrwxrwx 1 usr usr 4096 Oct  4 09:47 elasticsearch
drwxrwxrwx 1 usr usr 4096 Oct  4 09:47 rabbitmq
drwxrwxrwx 1 usr usr 4096 Oct 10 11:24 .
-rwxrwxrwx 1 usr usr 1713 Oct 10 11:24 docker-compose.base.yml
drwxrwxrwx 1 usr usr 4096 Oct 10 11:25 Envoy
drwxrwxrwx 1 usr usr 4096 Nov 22 09:33 ..

Prompt> find ./ -maxdepth 3 -type d
./
./elasticsearch
./elasticsearch/data
./elasticsearch/data/nodes
./Envoy
./mssqlserver
./mssqlserver/data
./rabbitmq
./rabbitmq/data
./rabbitmq/data/mnesia
./rabbitmq/log
```

Where can I look for the mentioned information?

Oh, I've launched a "find in file(s)", looking for the "FROM" keyword, and I found something in the "Envoy" container. Does this mean that that "Envoy" container is what you call the base image?

Here's the entry:

```
./Envoy/Dockerfile:FROM envoyproxy/envoy-dev:9105f45c7fb872d1db2bf8q9bc608368effe77cd
```

Comment: there are the `docker-compose.override.yaml`-files. But apart from this, when you call `docker run` from within VS, VS sets those variables for you.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain: Thanks for the quick reply. Nice try, but I don't have any `*.override.yaml` files, I only have a `docker-compose.yml` and a `docker-compose.base.yml` file, both in the `DockerCompose` directory.

Comment: They could come from your base image, what is it?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε: what do you mean by base image? I have a Docker-Compose application on my Windows-10 machine, containing different Docker containers, which are all Linux-based. As far as I know, there is nothing in common between the different Linux containers, or am I missing something? (I'm a newbie in Docker development)

Comment: Docker compose is nothing more than a wrapper around docker commands, so behind that you have Dockerfile(s) that all have a base image. (`FROM ...`).

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε. Indeed, and I have been looking like crazy for the mentioned environment variables but I don't find them anywhere. Do you have any idea where they are coming from? (I'm especially interested in `DOTNET_VERSION`)

Comment: @Dominique if you do provide what the base image is/are (what are the `...` in the `FROM ...`). line, then that would probably be easy to answer. Without it, well, that's plain guessing.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε: my answer on your last comment is too long, I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε: meanwhile I've understood that the "Envoy" container is a communication "device", so it's not the base image you were mentioning.

Comment: Can you share your docker-compose files? Those will specify what image you're building, and we can take it from there

Comment: @canton7: thanks for your remark: in the docket compose file, I have found a reference towards an image I have no access to (`image: registry.gitlab.com/username/registry/own_service:latest`). Once my colleague is back, I'll ask him to update that image. Thanks for your support.